# Number format exception when trying to parse string to integer

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to convert a user selected JTable column into an ArrayList. All the columns are strings (from a database) so the casting should happen on selection of the column. When I use the code below however I get a NumberformatException and I'm not really sure why.

```
TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
columnModel.addColumnModelListener(new TableColumnModelListener() {
// other methods
public void columnSelectionChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    Object[] data = columnToArray(table,table.getSelectedColumn());
    ArrayList<Float> descstats=new ArrayList<Float>();
    System.out.println("MY data length"+data.length);
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if (data[i]!=null){      
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt((data[i]).toString().trim()));
                descstats.add(Float.parseFloat((data[i]).toString().trim()));
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    float sum = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: can you please post the error stacktrace? and data example you pass to this method??

Comment: Guess: You do `Integer.parseInt` and then save the value with `Float.parseFloat`. If the number is float, `Integer.parseInt` will fail, it won't cast to int (i.e. `Integer.parseInt("6,2")` gives exception, it doesn't return 6).

Comment: What are you inputting that causes this exception?

Comment: Sorry just realised it was an error at the System.out line and its because I was casting as Integer when the number is Float. DUmb

Comment: BackSlash do you want the points? Post as answer tho I realised at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (data[i] != null) {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt((data[i]).toString().trim()));
    descstats.add(Float.parseFloat((data[i]).toString().trim()));
}
```

You do `Integer.parseInt` and then save the value with `Float.parseFloat`. If the number is `float`, `Integer.parseInt` will fail, it **won't** cast to `int` (i.e. `Integer.parseInt("6.2")` will raise a  `NumberFormatException`, it won't return `6`)